# Ledger sent eth to uniswap router and now swap was completed why is that?

Tags: etherscan, uniswap, ledger-nano-s

I made a swap on my ledger using wallet connect and instead of swapping the coins on uniswap it sent the eth to the router and no coins were swapped

Any idea why that would be and if there is anything I can do?

Here is the transaction

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xad76107856588b3119f09eaf85abb3a0e0d4f5520f12de05bd62bab6021a9ac2